# How to call rsync that it works with old and new versions of rsync without using the "old" way?

Tags: rsync

Rsync version 3.2.4 introduce a [behavior change](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/NEWS.html#BEHAVIOR_CHANGES-3.2.4) about a new way of arg protection. This is relevant when you have files or folders with spaces in their filename.

I know the argument `--old-args`. But that is a workaround and still forces the "old way". My goal is instead:

1. Use the "new" arg protection way introduced with 3.2.4
2. Scripts using that "way" should work with old and new versions of rsync **without** checking for the rsync version on the current system.

I am not sure how to do this but I have an idea.

In the past I did this (which worked for rsync before 3.2.3 and older; but won't work with 3.2.4 or newer)

```
rsync -aiv host:"a simple file.pdf" .
```

## Possible solution

My intended solution is to use `-s` which is present in older rsync versions also:

```
--protect-args, -s       no space-splitting; wildcard chars only
```

And  I replace the `"` with `'` like this

```
rsync -aiv host:'a simple file.pdf' . -s
```

This seems to work in my test environments. But I am not sure if this is OK.

The advantage of the solution IMHO is

- It works with older versions of rsync
- With newer versions (3.2.6) the `-s` seems to be the default behavior.

*Sidenote*: the long version of `-s` was `--protect-args` but was then [renamed to `--secluded-args` in rsync 3.2.6](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/NEWS.html#ENHANCEMENTS-3.2.6) “to make it clearer how it differs from the default backslash-escaped arg-protecting behavior of rsync”. However, the old name `--protect-args` is still accepted.

Comment: Are you doing all rsync actions on only 1 host, or are you trying to have rsync_V1 on host A interact with rsync_V2 on host B ?  If all on only 1 host, there is no need for concern.  Just use the new rsync.  The "old style" quotes are a temporary during transfer but do not remain on the files after the transfer.  I have no experience with inter-host transfers so could not advise on that scenario.

Comment: There are different rsync versions. Sometimes the local rsync is used. Sometimes rsync instance on a remote machine is used via SSH. Several combinations are possible. That is why I have goal 2. Btw: The [maintainer himself did proof my approach](https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2022-September/032882.html).

Comment: "without checking for the rsync version ..."? But that's the easy way. `ssh root@target rsync -v` is easily parsed. If you don't know which version you're talking to, how will you know what to say? What if there's a third `rsync` version that's different?

Comment: It is not designed to work like that. "--version", "-VV", "-V", "-v" produce very different output depending on the switch and on the string. I do know that because I do parse that in my [diagnostic output](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime/blob/dev/common/diagnostics.py). Rsyncs argument protection is designed to work like that without checking the version. I'm also in dialog with rsync maintainer. Despite of rsync, checking versions produce extra code, extra code flows, etc pp. Hard to maintain for years. It is bad practice.